# How to execute steaming data communication between HLS IP and SDK?

Tags: c, sdk, vivado-hls

Currently I'm working with Kintex 7 and microblaze, for pseudo-random bit sequence function. I have executed PRBS in HLS and created HLS IP, then integrated HLS IP with vivado, generated bit stream and exported it to SDK.

Actually, I need to return Pseudo_random bit sequences like 0's and 1's into XSDK through HLS IP.

But in SDK, I am getting only “Single bit” value (either 0 or 1) instead of sequence of random bits. How to get sequences of random bits between HLS IP and SDK?

Comment: Could you post some example code for your issue? At least the top function signature and the interface directives?

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Welcome-Join/How-to-get-random-bit-sequence-in-XSDK-from-HLS-IP/m-p/763597#M44714)

`int PRBS_prj()
{

int start_state = 0xCD;
int lfsr = start_state;
bool bit;
unsigned period = 0;
do
 {
  /* taps:  3, 2 and 1 ; feedback polynomial:  x^3 + x^2 + 1 */
  bit = ((lfsr >> 0) ^ (lfsr >> 2) ^ (lfsr >> 3) ^ (lfsr >> 4) ) & 1;
  printf("%d", bit);
  lfsr = (lfsr >> 1) | (bit << 7);
   ++period;
 } while (lfsr != start_state);
return bit;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the function you implemented has a single bit as its return value. This means it is expected to generate a single bit on every invocation. If you want more than one bit on each invocation, perhaps you can return an `ap_uint` of the width you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That mean you telling me to write program for PRBS using **C++ Arbitrary Precision Types**.

Comment: Yes, although, if you just need 64 bits at a time or 32 bits you can use ordinary C types.

Comment: I am trying for 32 bits or 64 bits only. In hls, i am getting sequence of bits, whereas in UART i am getting only single bit return through communication between HLS IP and XSDK. Why this issue i am facing ? Any UART return problem

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the testbench as well?